# Asp.net MVC 5 stored procedure resulting in empty complex type

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using asp.net mvc 5 with mysql. I have a stored procedure that takes 3 parameters and returns 3 columns given below

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ReportUsProjectWorkHours(IN userID INT(11), startDate VARCHAR(10), endDate VARCHAR(10))
    BEGIN
        SELECT tdd.tdd_day, ctd.ctd_name, tdd.workhours
        FROM timesheet_day_details tdd
        INNER JOIN timesheet_details tsd ON tdd.tsd_id = tsd.tsd_id
        INNER JOIN category_type_details ctd ON tsd.tsd_category_type_id = ctd.ctd_id
        INNER JOIN timesheets ts ON ts.timesheet_id = tsd.tsd_timesheet_id
        WHERE tsd.tsd_category_id = (SELECT category_id
                                     FROM categories
                                     WHere category_name = "projects")

    AND(tdd.tdd_day between startDate AND endDate)
    AND ts.timesheet_user = userID#(SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user = userID)
    ORDER BY tdd.tdd_day ASC;
END //
DELIMITER;
```

which works perfectly when called `CALL  ReportUsProjectWorkHours(1, "2018/06/18", "2018/06/24");`

I'm using entity framework and when I import the model function import for the stored procedure is generated along with complex type. Now from Get Column Information I can see that all 3 columns that are supposed to be returned are there but [the complex type always end up being empty for some reason as seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqxr2.png)

I tried adding them manually to model but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: rewrite this query using EF and forget about stored procedure =)

Comment: I have to filter among a large amount to data and that will slow down the processing significantly

Comment: If it is your real stored procedure code, then there is no difference between  linq-query (which will transform into the **same** sql query) or this stored procedure. Because in stored procedure you are doing 1 simple select.

Comment: @HemidAbbasov actually if you look closely there are subqueries and other things, it's not just a basic SELECT. Entity Framework is notorious for producing very inefficient SQL for anything more than the simplest query. In my practical experience of a moderately complex schema and queries in a recent project, moving from EF queries to views or stored procedures resulted in speed improvements of 10x or more, especially for larger datasets.